# No simple closed form for Bell numbers

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, soft-question, integer-partitions

The Bell number $B_n$ is the number of partitions of $[n]$. Unlike other basic combinatorial quantities, $B_n$ has no simple finite closed form. This seems surprising to me. Can anyone explain why this is the case, or lead me to references that discuss the matter further?

Comment: There are links at https://oeis.org/A000110 to many many papers about the Bell numbers. Maybe one of them addresses your question. Have a look, and report back to us if you find anything interesting.

Comment: Have a chance yet to look at those links?

Comment: Yes I looked at those links. I couldn't seem to locate any discussion along the lines of my question - that is to say, intuition about why a certain quantity can't be expressed in a certain manner.

Comment: The premise of your question is somewhat unclear, because "*closed form*" is a somewhat variable quantity. Unless you allow factorials in a closed form, I can't think of any basic combinatorial quantity which has one. Allowing them lets in binomial coefficients and therefore Catalan numbers, but what else? Such basic combinatorial quantities as Stirling numbers and the partition function don't have well-known closed forms.

Answer (score 1):

With $S_{n,k}$ the Stirling number of the second kind:

$B_n=\sum_{k=0}^nS_{n,k}$

This is already a finite closed form expression.

If you mean finite closed form expressions without a sum sign:

If combinatorial numbers are more complex, e.g. more complex composed from other combinatorial numbers, than they have no finite closed form expression. Usual representations are generating functions (e.g. sums, products, continued fractions) and recurrence equations. Also some fundamental combinatorial quantities cannot be represented in closed form. Look e.g. for the partition function p(n).

There are some mathematical theories which classes of generating functions or  recurrence equations have representations in finite closed form.